# Change button twice

Tags: javascript, web

I want to change the button options when clicked, but I can't figure out how to do it after it changes once. I want to list the next choices for the next question after I click either the yes or no option.

```
document.getElementById("pack1").onclick = function() {
    nextQuestion();
    fail++;
    choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='feed1'>Yes</button> <br><button id='feed2'>No</button>";
};

document.getElementById("pack2").onclick = function() {
    nextQuestion();
    fail++;
    choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='feed1'>Yes</button> <br><button id='feed2'>No</button>";
};

document.getElementById("pack3").onclick = function() {
    nextQuestion();
    fail++;
    choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='feed1'>Yes</button> <br><button id='feed2'>No</button>";
};
```

was my first attempt and I after I tried:

```
//variables
const spanElement = document.querySelector(".span");
const spanElement1 = document.querySelector(".span1");
const spanElement2 = document.querySelector(".span2");
const spanElement3 = document.querySelector(".span3");
const choicesElement = document.getElementById("choicespan");
const btnElement = document.querySelector(".choices");
let success = 0;
let fail = 0;
let index = 0;
let index1 = 0;
const myList = ["The leader of your group says to feed your horses before you leave. Do you feed them?", "Your leader, John Bartleson, has told you that it's time to start your journey. You're on the trail, but your son has to go to the bathroom; what do you do?", "Your daughter complains of hunger. What do you do?", "You reach a stop shortly, and John announces, 'Alright, cook meals, hunt, anything. Be back before dawn and be ready to go.'", "You sleep until five in the morning when you are woken up by a cow bell sound. At which point there is someone telling everyone to get up and ready. Your son is groaning about having to wake up what do you do?", "After much more travel, your group comes upon a boulder blocking your path."];

//first question and options
spanElement.textContent = ">-----------------<";
spanElement1.textContent = "You are in Independence, Missouri. You and other fur traders and trappers are going to explore the northwest. What do you pack?";
choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='pack1' class='choices'>Lantern</button> <br><button id='pack2' class='choices'>Lantern and butter churn</button> <br><button id='pack3' class='choices'>Butter churn</button> <br><button id='pack4' class='choices'>Box</button> <br><button id='pack5' class='choices'>Barrel</button> <br><button id='pack6' class=choices'>Butter churn and box</button> <br><button id='pack7' class='choices'>Butter churn and barrel</button> <br><button id='pack8' class='choices'>Lantern and box</button> <br><button id='pack9' class='choices'>Lantern and barrel</button> <br><button id='pack10' class='choices>Box and barrel</button> <br><button id='pack11' class='choices'>Pot</button> <br><button id='pack12' class='choices'>Medicine, water, and other bottled liquids</button> <br><button id='pack13' class='choices'>Pot and box</button> <br><button id='pack14' class='choices'>Pot and barrel</button> <br><button id='pack15' class='choices'>Pot and lantern</button> <br><button id='pack16' class='choices'>Pot and butter churn</button> <br><button id='pack17' class='choices'>Pot and medicine</button> <br><button id='pack18' class='choices'>Medicine and box</button> <br><button id='pack19' class='choices'>Medicine and barrel</button> <br><button id='pack20' class='choices'>Medicine and lantern</button> <br><button id='pack21' class='choices'>Medicine and butter churn</button> <br><button id='pack22' class='choices'>All</button>";

//function to check what the question is and change it
function nextQuestion() {
    if (index < myList.length) {
        document.getElementById("span1").textContent = myList[index];
        index++;
    };
};

//change choices
function changeQuestion() {
    nextQuestion();
    choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='feed1' class='choices'>Yes</button> <br><button id='feed2' class='choices'>No</button>"
};


//where the problem arises
function changeQuestionAgain() {
    if (changeQuestion() == true) {
        nextQuestion();
        choicesElement.innerHTML = "<button id='bath1' class='choices'>Pull over</button> <br><button id='bath2' class='choices'>Let him go in the pot</button> <br><button id='bath3' class='choices'>Tell him to hold it until the whole group stops</button>";
    };
};

//check which answer and add points
btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeQuestion();
    if($("div").attr("id") == "pack22" || "feed1") {
        success++;
    };
});
```

which is closer but still doesn't work

Here is my html and css by the way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Oregon Trail</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game-container">
            <h1>Oregon Trail</h1>
            <h1><span class="span"></span></h1>
            <h2><span class="span2"></span></h2>
            <h2><span class="span3"></span></h2>
            <h2><span id="span1" class="span1"></span></h2>
            <h2><span id="choicespan" class="choices"></span></h2>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: lime;
}

#game-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: lime;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  transparent 0%,
  transparent 90%,
  lime 90%,
  lime 100%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  background-position-x: right;
  
  transition: background-size 300ms;
}

button:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position-x: left;
}
```

Comment: *I want to list the next choices for the next question after I click either the yes or no option.* ... Identify the types of questions you will be prompting and then write code to support each type, no matter what the question is. Then store your questions and their possible answers to an array or some resource that you pull them from as needed. Because the way you are going about it now wont scale and is the source of your difficulty.